# Manipulate variables in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, variables

Is it possible to manipulate a variable, for example:
`file = "/Python/work.txt"`

to just list work.txt, without /Python? excluding everything on the left of the "/"?

Thank you

Comment: BTW, that's not valid Python syntax: you forgot the quotes.

Comment: Since you're using Python 3, I recommend that you become familiar with the awesome [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, which is very handy for all sorts of path manipulation tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course! Simply do this:

```
file = "/Python/work.txt"
excluded = file.split("/")[-1]
```

This would return "work.txt" in the excluded variable.

Comment: No. Use the `os` module. The code won't be portable if you hardcode the separator.

Comment: It's a good idea to do a search for duplicates when you see a question that's probably been asked before.

Comment: @timgeb `os` is old-school. All the cool kids use `pathlib`. ;)